# Is there a way to redirect https to http on IIS 7?

Tags: iis-7, ssl, ssl-certificate

We have not purchased an SSL certificate so the user of our website has to click to "approve" the website everytime they use it. Is there a quick way to redirect all https:// traffic to http:// for now in IIS 7? So that all content is served as under http://

By the way I DO NOT have "Require SSL" ticked under SSL settings.

Also if I purchase an SSL certificate, how would I point it so that IIS 7 on my server can use it and allow the user entry without warning them everytime?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a quick way to redirect all https:// traffic to http:// for now

Not really. The redirect can be done, of course, but the redirect response itself must be signed with a trusted certificate or the user will get the same warning as before.

This makes sense: otherwise, a man-in-the-middle attacker could simply respond to a user's HTTPS request with a redirect to HTTP (or a different HTTPS site) and take over the browsing session, defeating the purpose of SSL.

If you get your certificate signed by a trusted CA you can just import it in the same way as the current self-signed cert. Some CAs may require extra cert chains but that's CA-specific: you'll find the relevant details for setting up web servers including IIS7 with those certs on all good CA sites.

Comment: In that case we can't get a SSL cert for a short period, what I mean is then, can I just remove the https site binding altogether and will http work for users? If so how is this done in IIS&

Comment: Yes, you can remove the https site binding (from the site in the left pane, choose the ‘Bindings...’ action) and http will continue to work. Users typing ‘https’ will simply fail to get any kind of connection (assuming you have no other https site bindings set up).